# c++ passing functions with variable number of arguments as argument to other function

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I wrote a C++ class that parses expressions like "2 * SQRT(5) + 1". I've created a class called `c_function` that "represents" the usual mathematical functions like `sqrt`, `sin`, `cos` etc. something like as follows:

```
class c_function {
  std::string name;
  double (*function)(double);

public:
  c_function(std::string fname, double (*ffunction)(double)) {
    name = fname;
    function = ffunction;
  }

// ...
};
```

Then I have a different class that contains a `std::vector` of these `c_function` objects:

```
class expression {
  std::vector<c_function> functions;
  // etc...

public:
  // ctor:
  expression(/* ... */) {
    // ...
    functions.push_back(c_function("SQRT", sqrt));
    functions.push_back(c_function("SIN" , sin));
    functions.push_back(c_function("COS" , cos));
    // ...
  }

};
```

The point is that all these functions have one argument. That is fine for most cases but I want to enable adding custom functions to the `expression` class and also want to support custom functions with more that one argument (for example, to define a function `AREA(a, b)` that returns the product of the two values a and b).

I did that by adding an argument counter `argumentCount` and more function "properties" to the `c_function` class:

```
class c_function {
  std::string name;
  unsigned int argumentCount;
  double (*function1)(double);
  double (*function2)(double, double);

  // ...
};
```

and used two constructors:

```
c_function(std::string fname, double (*ffunction)(double)) {
  name = fname;
  argumentCount = 1;
  function1 = ffunction;
  function2 = NULL;
};
c_function(std::string fname, double (*ffunction)(double, double)) {
  name = fname;
  argumentCount = 2;
  function1 = NULL;
  function2 = ffunction;
};
```

and added the methods to the `expression` class:

```
// add custom function with one argument
void addFunction(std::string fname, double (*ffunction)(double));

// add custom function with two arguments
void addFunction(std::string fname, double (*ffunction)(double, double));
```

so that one can define

```
double Expression_Area(double width, double height) {
  return (width * height);
}
```

and introduce it to the `expression` class with

```
myExpression.addFunction("AREA", Expression_Area);
```

That works fine and this way I can also add more function "properties" and functions constructors allowing any number of arguments, but

1. there is always a limit of the number of arguments that is supported
2. the code becomes ugly by having multiple constructors, methods to add a function, and code within the interpretation of the expression just because the number of arguments may be different.

I wonder if there is a way to support functions with any number of arguments more general. I tried changing the `c_function` class to:

```
class c_function {
  std::string name;
  unsigned int argumentCount;
  double (*function)(...);
  // ...

};
```

but this does not work because functions with fixed number of arguments are not accepted by `(...)`.

Is there any way to get this solved with one constructor, one function "property" etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### C++11 onwards

In C++11 you can use a variadic template to declare a class that will take a function with a variable number of arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double bar(double x) {
  return x;
}

double bar2(double x, double y) {
  return x+y;
}

template <typename... Args>
class Foo {
public:
  Foo (const std::string& name, double (*func)(Args...))
    : name_{name}, func_{func} {}

  double call(Args... args) {
    return func_(args...);
  }

  // Thanks to W.F. for reminding me of the operator() overload
  // This does the same thing as a call to the "call" method.
  double operator()(Args... args) {
    return func_(args...);
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  double (*func_)(Args...);
};

int main() {
  Foo<double> t1("test1", bar);
  Foo<double, double> t2("test2", bar2);

  // NOTE: in C++17 you can declare Foo without the template
  // arguments: they will be deduced.
  // Foo t1("test1", bar); // C++17
  // Foo t2("test2", bar2); // C++17

  std::cout << t1.call(14) << ' ' << t2(14, 56) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You can tweak this basic solution as to how you need your classes to work.

### C++98

Pre C++11, you will probably be forced to create classes that take functions with a different number of arguments, so your classes would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double bar(double x) {
  return x;
}

double bar2(double x, double y) {
  return x+y;
}

class Foo1 {
public:
  // let's typedef the function pointer for two reasons:
  //   1. readability
  //   2. duplicating the class for a different number of arguments
  //      means we need to do less modifications to the code because
  //      we can catch a few changes in one line here.
  typedef double (*Function)(double);

  Foo1 (const std::string& name, const Function func)
    : name_(name), func_(func) {}

  double operator()(double x) {
    return func_(x);
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  Function func_;
};

class Foo2 {
public:
  typedef double (*Function)(double, double);

  Foo2 (const std::string& name, const Function func)
    : name_(name), func_(func) {}

  double operator()(double x, double y) {
    return func_(x, y);
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  Function func_;
};

// etc. for classes Foo3, Foo4, ... up until you think you will
// need no more.

int main() {
  Foo1 t1("test1", bar);
  Foo2 t2("test2", bar2);

  std::cout << t1(14) << ' ' << t2(14, 56) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

There's a bit of code duplication here, but it's not too bad.

### Remarks

Finally, (although I did not show it above because I think it goes without saying) wherever there is code duplication, template the types so that you can reduce this as much as possible. So, for example, you might consider modifying the C++11 `Foo` class above to:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Foo {
public:
  typedef T (*Function)(Args...);

  Foo (const std::string& name, const Function func)
    : name_{name}, func_{func} {}

  T operator()(Args... args) {
    return func_(args);
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  Function    func_;
};
```

Comment: you could overload `operator()` to let it look more like function invocation :)

Comment: @W.F. yeah whatever... :)

Comment: Thanks Zorawar for the good hints. The solution using code duplication is what I already have (a bit different but logically the same). My fault to see that there is no way around duplication when calling the functions while interpreting because the arguments between the function parenteses are collected in a vector<double> that must be passed somehow to the function. This would be possible within an implicit loop (I remember that from Fortran format statement) but I believe that is not available in C++. Anyway, your hint reduces code duplication to one place instead of four.

Comment: @Armin: there may be a way to do this (but possibly it will be ugly and almost definitely you will need C++11 or C++17 to do it) but you should definitely ask _another_ question about this problem. I will think about it, but possibly someone else will know how to do it. Go for it and ask :)

Comment: @Zorawar: Done, I'm looking forward to the answers.